# Storing a List in a Vertex using Gremlin and Azure Cosmos Graph

Tags: neo4j, azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am trying to store a list of changes made to a Vertex in the Vertex itself. Ideally I would want something like this:

```json
{
    "id": "95fcfa87-1c03-436d-b3ca-340cea926ee9",
    "label": "person",
    "type": "vertex",
    "log": [{
            "user": "user@user.dk",
            "action": "update",
            "timestamp": "22-03-2017",
            "field": "firstName",
            "oldValue": "Marco"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using this method chain I am able to a achieve the following structure

```cs
graph.addV('person')
     .property('firstName', 'Thomas')
     .property(list, 'log', '22-03-2017')
     .properties('log')
     .hasValue('22-03-2017', '21-03-2017')
     .property('user','user@user.dk')
     .property('action', 'update')
     .property('field', 'firstName')
     .property('oldValue', 'Marco')
```

> ```
> {
>     "id": "95fcfa87-1c03-436d-b3ca-340cea926ee9",
>     "label": "person",
>     "type": "vertex",
>     "properties": {
>         "firstName": [{
>                 "id": "f23482a9-48bc-44e0-b783-3b74a2439a11",
>                 "value": "Thomas"
>             }
>         ],
>         "log": [{
>                 "id": "5cfa35e1-e453-42e2-99b1-eb64cd853f22",
>                 "value": "22-03-2017",
>                 "properties": {
>                     "user": "user@user.dk",
>                     "action": "update",
>                     "field": "firstName",
>                     "oldValue": "Marco"
>                 }
>             }
>         ]
>     }
> }
> ```

However this seems overly complex, as I will have to store a value and add properties to it.
Is it possible to add anonymous objects (i.e. without `id` and `value`) with the above mentioned data?

Comment: Using Gremlin vertex properties with list and meta-properties is the only way to have more complex entities that are also queryable on the Vertex. One thing to keep in mind is that Vertex size is limited to 2MB (actual size of Vertex as stored in CosmosDB will differ from the size of Vertex response), so if the log data is expected to grow without regular cleanup, you may want to consider a different data model (perhaps chunks of log data are stored in separate vertices)

Comment: @OliverTowers Thank you and good point. Having what is virtually an unbounded list in a size limited structure sounds like a bad idea. If you create an answer with this, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Not an actual solution to storing proper objects in a history log, but if you just use it as a log and don't have to access or query it by its properties, you could just put the serialised JSON in the value?

Something like along these lines should approximate the structure you're requesting:

```cs
dynamic entry = new JObject();
entry.user = "user@user.dk";
entry.action = "update";
entry.timestamp = "22-03-2017 12:34:56";
entry.field = "firstName";
entry.oldValue = "Marco";

graph.addV('person')
     .property('firstName', 'Thomas')
     .property(list, 'log', entry.ToString());
```

> ```
> {
>     "id": "95fcfa87-1c03-436d-b3ca-340cea926ee9",
>     "label": "person",
>     "type": "vertex",
>     "properties": {
>         "firstName": [{
>                 "id": "f23482a9-48bc-44e0-b783-3b74a2439a11",
>                 "value": "Thomas"
>             }
>         ],
>         "log": [{
>                 "id": "5cfa35e1-e453-42e2-99b1-eb64cd853f22",
>                 "value": "{\"user\":\"user@user.dk\",\"action\":\"update\",\"timestamp\":\"22-03-2017\",\"field\":\"firstName\",\"oldValue\":\"Marco\"}"
>             }
>         ]
>     }
> }
> ```

These log entries can easily be read, deserialised, used, and presented, but will not do much for queriability.

Comment: An interesting idea, however we need to be able to query this.